# Is there a way to programmatically override "Incoming Call" screen on Blackberry for incoming calls?

Tags: blackberry, mobile-phones

Is there a way to programmatically override "Incoming Call" screen on Blackberry for incoming calls?

Basically, pop up a different screen that would show call information in better layout and allow to answer or hang-up call.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible - see this post on the BB Java Development Forums:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=17595

There are other posts in that forum as well indicating that you cannot interrupt the incoming call screen, you cannot bring your application to the foreground until the call has been either ignored or connected.

If you can handle that route (which is unlikely), you will need to implement the PhoneListener interface's callIncoming method.